# Pyinstaller on MACOs-Homebrew with PyGobject

Tags: macos, homebrew, pyinstaller, pygobject, py2app

I am desperately trying to create an executeable *.app-file from my small program for Mac users.
My script is running on Linux and Windows and I even was able to get a compiled Windows exe with pyinstaller. Since some friends asked, I wanted to make it available for MAC, too.

I was able to get the script running on MAC with Python3 being installed via **Homebrew** as well as PyGobject and GTK. Small downside is that program icon is not loaded in MAC (in Linux and Windows it is).
Unfortunately I wasn't able to create a working *.app-file from within the homebrew environment. I tried **pyinstaller**, since that worked under Windows. Even though I chose the MAC specific options, the result is not working. The final file is just 6 MB in size (in Windows it's over 200 MB) and, with console-option on, it tells me that the module "gi" can't be imported. So somehow Pyinstaller is not integrating the PyGobject installation in the Homebrew location although PyGobject is successfully located and loaded when starting python via the terminal.

I also tried **py2app**, which created a 300 MB file, but this file fails starting up without notice. I don't know why, but maybe it is because of the subfolders I use in my script.

Googling hasn't helped me so far.
I appreciate any help and hints with either of both tools! I apologize in advance if that question is well known with MAC users, but I'm unfamiliar with that system.

Key facts: Python3.9, Latest PyGobject versions (updated today), Pyinstaller 4.1

Script can be found at: [codeberg.org/codade/KYSA](https://codeberg.org/codade/KYSA)

Comment: Did you get this working?  I also want to bundle up a PyGObject application as a macOS app.

Comment: Hi, yes i finally managed to build the app. I had to reinstall Homebrew completely to fix path issues, but finally it worked. If you're using multiprocessing maybe this is also interesting for you https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5553, as I had some issues with the icons and queuing. Good luck!